# Как работают brawl stars боты?

Tags: brawlstars.py

Знаю, немного не по теме форума, но по какому принципу они работают? Например Zer0_bot работает на сервере с 193 ГБ оперативки, чего не хватит для создания сотен ботов с интеграцией через bluestacks. Каким образом они взаимодействуют с игрой, если у brawl stars'а нету api (в плане управления игроком)?

Comment: Stack overflow на русском это **НЕ** форум!!